# Jersey not capturing an exception

Tags: java, exception, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

My implementation of `ExceptionMapper` looks like below:

```
@Provider
public class CaptureUnhandledExceptions implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable>
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogFactory.getLogger(CaptureUnhandledExceptions.class);

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable exception)
    {
        LOGGER.error("Unhandled exception", exception);
        ErrorMessage em = new ErrorMessage(50099, ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(exception).getMessage(),
                exception.getMessage());
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(em).build();
    }
}
```

In my REST api, I am trying pass wrong value for my `JSON` body, but it is throwing following exception

```
Can not deserialize value of type com.abccompany.model.ConnectionEndpoint$Binding from String "RandomValue: value not one of declared Enum instance names: [POST, REDIRECT]
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@3fce79f3; line: 16, column: 28] (through reference chain: com.abccompany.model.SpConnection["connection"]->com.abccompany.model.Connection["connectionendpoints"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.abccompany.model.ConnectionEndpoint["endpointbinding"])
```

what am I missing? Do I have to register my provider in `ResourceConfig`?

In ResourceConfig of application

```
this.register(com.abccompany.utils.CaptureUnhandledExceptions.class);
```

Comment: Have you seen the "Unhandled exception" in your logfile? You do not need to register your custom exception handler class.

Comment: No...I did that just to make sure I was not missing anything

Comment: Try to throw a new Exception("say something...") in your rest method deliberately to see what will happen.

Comment: I guess I figured out. I had to add `this.register(com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);` in my ResourceConfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to add `this.register(com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJs‌​onProvider.class);` in `ResourceConfig`